# PHP fetching data from URL

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm having problems with fetching data from URL. When I input URL in browser file normally gets downloaded to my computer, but when I try to access it in my code I get response FALSE, with no errors just bool(false) response. It's function for ICAL sync and 3 or 4 urls are fine but that one is just not getting data. Tried both with **file_get_contents** and with **CURL**. Here is **CURL** function:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Here are some info about server:

> PHP Version = 5.6.10-pl0
>
> allow_url_fopen = On
>
> OpenSSL support   = enabled

And yeah file is on **HTTPS** server if that's maybe an issue. Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: `curl` has an error code if the download didn't work. Please add this error code

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer here it is:

error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer So I guess it's problem with SSL Certificate but on my side or?

Comment: `sslv3` ??? Ah.

Comment: Also may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759383/ssl-error-can-not-change-to-tls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer local refers to your server, remote to the other one (the one you are trying to access).

From the error message:

> SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

it looks like your client and the server implementation cannot agree on a common cipher suite to use. This usually means one implementation is a bit dated.

There is no problem with the remote certificate. This would have yielded a different error message.

## Check the remote server

You can use for example [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to determine which Protocol versions and ciphers the remote server is using.

Then you can select some of them for curl to use ([Source for code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34244548/1392490)):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,...');
```

## Check the local/your server

You said you are using PHP 5.6.10. **This is quite a bit out of date.** (It was released on 11 Jun 2015). The current `5.6` version branch is at 5.6.34. If I was you I would consider an upgrade.

From the SSL Server test: The remote server only accepts `TLS1.2`. So you should also consider upgrading your OpenSSL installation.

Some more links for reference:

- https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html

Comment: Thank you man so far. I get this from testing server: https://imgur.com/a/vA2ao . So what Cipher list to use?

Comment: This only shows the certificate. That is irrelevant in the handshake process

Comment: Okay I found section with Cipher and it says: 

Cipher Suites
# TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

But when I try to setup either of this it gets error: failed setting cipher list. So I guess my server with that version of openssl doesn't support it?

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect that. If is answers your question, [please accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Okay thank you @rollstuhlfahrer for everything. Was lost for about 1-2 hours about this one.